# The element type 'Set<Text>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

With the following code, I am trying to add a new `Text` widget for each player:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              for (var player in _players) {Text(player.name)}
            ],
          )
       ]));
}
```

This results in the following error:

> The element type 'Set' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I answered this question already. Let me quickly find the answer :)

Comment: Getting another error: `type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Player>'`

Comment: Removed the curly braces. This is the error now. Is there something wrong with what I am doing with the json array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are creating a `Set` using the curly braces ([set literal](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets)). Your build function should look exactly like this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              for (var player in _players) Text(player.name)
            ],
          )
       ]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
children: _players.map((player) => Text(player.name)).toList(),
```